# Proper Scaling and Zooming into Window in QGIS

Tags: qgis

My attribute tables and icons are tiny in QGIS.

I believe this may be because I have a new high-res monitor.

Check out my screenshots - everything is super tiny. And in the attribute table, the row heights are not right.

Also - How do I zoom into the attribute table?? Normally this is ctrl-mouse wheel or ctrl+/-

Can't seem to find an answer to my question anywhere.

[image: QGIS Main Window]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given by @Stu Smith [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163414/making-icons-and-text-larger-on-high-resolution-screen-for-qgis/193683?noredirect=1#comment441511_193683), with some clarifications that we worked out.

The detailed directions are [here](http://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/), written well for layman's, with step by step instructions and a nice video.

**What's great is you can do this for any program you're having a problem with.**

It's super easy, a 2-step 5 minute process. You have to add a file in the registry, and then in the Program Files folder, add another file.

Couple notes:

*For qgis specifically: where the following file is: *qgis-bin.exe* rename the file to add to the folder to *qgis-bin.exe.manifest*.

*When I chose decimal and reopen it, it shows that it's back to hexadecimal. This doesn't matter at all. An explanation is on the bottom [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/problem-with-regedit-fail-trying-to-modify-dword/c6cdf515-c517-4196-8d4a-582e942f9315).

*The resolution will be lower, and things will look that way. In this case, not really a big deal, should affect your results, but not sure with programs where resolution matters, like Photoshop. Anyone give their experience or knowledge with that in the comments.